# Mixin in TypeScript to already instantiated Object

Tags: javascript, object, typescript, interface, mixins

I'm using an external library, that returns an instantiated Object `a` of Type `A` in a callback, where `A` is defined as an **Interface** (the class imlementation of `A` is not exported by the external module):

```
extLib.on("someEvent", ((a: A) => { /*...*/ });
```

Now I'd like to add a mixin Object of Type `B` to the already existing instance of `A`:

```
class B {
   someExtension() { /* ... */ }
}
```

My current approach is somewhat lousy:

```
function Add_B(a: A): (A & B) {
    // cast to intersection type
    let _a = a as (A & B);
    _a.someExtension = () => { /* ... */ }
    return _a;
}

extLib.on("someEvent", ((a: A) => {
    let _a = Add_B(a);
    // mixin achieved, _a is of type (A & B)
});
```

Now does someone know of a better approach that would:

- Allow `B` to have callable constructor and have `B` be newable
- Result in less/cleaner code
- Has more expressive typings than the `A & B` intersection type
- Would allow for `readonly` properties on `B`?
- Doesn't mess with the prototype chain too heavily (think `static` members)
  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
interface A {
    prop: string;
}

class B {
    // so the same function can be shared between instance of B and instances of A & B
    static someExtensionStatic = () => { /* ... */ }

    someExtension = B.someExtensionStatic;
    readonly prop2: number;
    constructor(a?:A) {
        if (a) {
            let a1 = a as AandB;
            a1.someExtension = B.someExtensionStatic;
            return a1;
        }
    }
}

type AandB = A & B;
```

and in your calling code:

```
extLib.on("someEvent", ((a: A) => {
    let _a = new B(a) as AandB;
    // mixin achieved, _a is of type (A & B)
}));
```

[Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20so%20the%20same%20function%20can%20be%20shared%20between%20instance%20of%20B%20and%20instances%20of%20A%20%26%20B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20someExtensionStatic%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%2F*%20...%20*%2F%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20someExtension%20%3D%20B.someExtensionStatic%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20prop2%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(a%3F%3AA)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(a)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20a1%20%3D%20a%20as%20AandB%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a1.someExtension%20%3D%20B.someExtensionStatic%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20a1%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20AandB%20%3D%20A%20%26%20B%3B)

One issue: the prototype of new instances of `B` will be at `B.prototype`, but instances of `A` will not have the prototype of `B.prototype`.

**Update**

A consequence of the difference in prototype will result in the following:

```
var b1 = new B();
var isInstanceOf = b1 instanceof B; // true

var b2 = new B(a);
isInstanceOf = b2 instanceof B;     // false
```

Therefore you should decide the type of the resulting object:

- an instance of A, augmented with the members of B

  In that case `new B(a)` doesn't make sense; a static `B.augment<T>: T & B` method would be more fitting
- an instance of B, augmented with members of A; and `instanceof` will work sensibly

Comment: Nice. The reason I couldn't come up with that is that I never imagined the return value of the constructor defines what instance new B() will be.. gues I am too much used to C# where a constructor can not have a return type :)

Comment: @Dyna Typescript doesn't either recognize that the constructor returns a different type, nor does it allow you to specify the return type of the constructor, which is why we have to cast in the calling code: `let _a = new B(a) as AandB;`.

Comment: @Dyna Thinking about this a bit more, I don't know how much point there is in using a constructor to return an arbitrary type (probably why Typescript doesn't allow type annotations on the constructor). Does it really make sense to call `new B(a)` and get back not an object with the prototype `B`, but an object unrelated to `B` (albeit with the same members as `B`). I would proably use a `static` method on `B`, and call it `B.create()` (which returns a new instance of `B`) or `B.create(a)` (which returns the augmented `A`. This would also allow for separate types based on the overload.

Comment: @Dyna Updated answer